# How to Zip Excel file using CLOSEDXML and Sharpziplib C#

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

i am new C# Beginner,
I created a function to generate Excel using ClosedXML.Excel, but i also want to zip the excel fill, how to  zip excel file using Sharpziplib? anybody could give an adivse?thanks

```
public FileResult Export()
{
    DataTable test = new DataTable("test");
    test.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {new DataColumn("Name")});

    foreach (var record in recordtest)
    {
         test.Rows.Add(record.name);
    }
 
    using (XLWorkbook ts = new XLWorkbook())
    {
          var testSheet = ts.Worksheets.Add(test);
          testSheet.Cell("D4").Value = "First Name";
          testSheet.Range("A4:A5").Merge();              
          testSheet.Range("A4:Q5").Columns().Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = 
     XLColor.Almond;
    }
    using (MemoryStream steam = new MemoryStream())
    {
           wb.SaveAs(steam);
           var fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}.xlsx", "test", 
               DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
           return File(steam.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
            officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: The same way you'd zip anything else using sharpziplib. Please show what you have tried with regards to zipping.

Comment: FYI, excel files are already zipped, so zipping again won't save much space.

Comment: You might want to save your workbook to a stream inside the scope of the xlworkbook disposable

Comment: Hi, thank all for the reply quickly.i have two excel file generate when i click excel export of the button, so i need to zip the two excel to the zip file, could you help me how to zip for excel file? thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want create zip, there are same way with CreateZipFile following this articles

- https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/tree/master/samples/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Samples/cs/CreateZipFile
- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/629/how-to-create-and-extract-zip-files-compress-and-decompress-zip-with-sharpziplib-with-csharp-in-winforms

Comment: This is a fairly low quality and brittle answer